# ValueError at /getGiftFromFaucet/ The view contract.views.getGiftFromFaucet didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, web3py

I'm doing my first question on StackOverFlow about something ig going me crazy.
My project is an Auction site, and is based on django and Web3 to interact with a smart contract deployed on my Ganache.

Now I have got this error on my view :

> ValueError at /getGiftFromFaucet/ The view contract.views.getGiftFromFaucet didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

The problem is:

If I register a customer and an address,
then I try to receive tokens from the Faucet,
If I put customer address I don't receive anything.
But if i select another address, I receive token in the first address.
I really don't understand why...

my Model:

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256,
                               blank=False,
                               null=False,
                               unique=True,
                               error_messages={'unique': 'This address is already registered'})
    tokenBalance = models.FloatField(default=0)
    dollarBalance = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

my Registration to the site

```
def registrationForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username,
                password=password,
            )
            newCustomer = Customer(
                user=user,
                dollarBalance=random.randrange(500, 1500),
                address=address,
                tokenBalance=0
            )
            user.save()
            newCustomer.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f'''Welcome in DNote {request.user}''')
            return redirect('homepage')

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'registration.html', context)
```

my Form:

```
class ReceiveTokenFromFaucet(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['address']
```

My view:

```
def getGiftFromFaucet(request):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
    customerAddress = customer.address
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReceiveTokenFromFaucet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            customerAddress = form.cleaned_data['address']
            if customerAddress not in alreadyRecompensed:
                contract.functions.transfer(
                    customerAddress,  100000000000000000000
                ).transact({'from': faucet})
                alreadyRecompensed.append(customerAddress)
                customer.tokenBalance += 100000000000000000000
                customer.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Your Tokens Are accreditate on your Account')
                return redirect('/homepage/')


            if customerAddress in alreadyRecompensed:
                messages.error(request, 'Already Recompensed')
                return redirect('/homepage/')

    else:
        form = ReceiveTokenFromFaucet()
        context = {'form': form, 'alreadyRecompensed': alreadyRecompensed}
        return render(request, 'requireFromFaucet.html', context)
```

My Html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{{ block.super }} ReceiveFreeTokens {% endblock head_title %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">

        <div class="col-4">

            <h2>DNote</h2>
            <h3>Receive Free Tokens</h3>
            <p>Available only one time</p>
            <br>

            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="max-width:100%">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Create">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Try to add some `else` block after all `if` block and put some `print('some text')` to have an idea of where the issue come from... *Sometime the request is POST but the form is not valid, what do you return in this case ???*

Comment: Thanks for the answer first :)

Comment: i already tried in 100 ways but i really don't understand, i tried now to deploy a new smart contract and change address, abi... but nothing. I Alway get this error if i put the right address, instead i receive tokens from my faucet if i put another address. The Point is: at the end all the user have the right balance but, to take free tokens from the faucet i have to put a different address to receive on the right address.... IS SOMETHING CRAZY :))

Comment: I tried your way and changed my view adding some else.... i think the form is not valid...but why?Any suggest?